# value of variables are not displayed via debugger

Tags: android, debugging

I am trying to learn how the debugger is working, so i created the below example and placed a breaking point at the line mentioned below in the code. When i ran the debugger, I expected the to see only the value of the varibale "a"
on the screen, but actually what happened is nothing was displayed at all

why the value of the variable "a" is not displayed on screen using the TextView "this.mTV2"?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.mTV1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    this.mTV2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    this.mTV3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv3);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    int a, b, c;
    int x = 30;
    int y = 40;
    int z = 50;

    a = x + y;
    b = y + z;
    c = x + z;

    this.mTV1.setText("" + a);
    this.mTV2.setText("" + b);//BREAKING POINT HERE
    this.mTV3.setText("" + c);
}
```

Comment: probably is not relevant, but just for a try can you put the code all inside the onCreate? and also can you provide the xml of the activity_main?

Comment: So you stepped past the "a" and then checked the value and it shows nothing? Or null?

Comment: Not absolutely certain, but I think the screen isn't drawn when the OnResume method is running, does it still not display after OnResume has finished?

Comment: @Cruces EDIT: I didn't read correctly, he said he doesn't see anything on screen. I thought on debugger. the problem is the one you pointed, true!

Comment: yeah but his problem was that the textview is not filled when the breakpoint hits, at that point the view may not have been drawn, that's why I'm asking if it still doesn't show the value after he continues with the execution and lets onresume finish

Comment: @Cruces yeah I missread the question. I edited the previous comment, you were right

Comment: @Danieboy it shows nothing

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley without using the debugger "when i run the code in the normal mode without debugging mode" it runs normally and every thing is displayed

Comment: @user2121 I tried to explain better in the answer below, have a look pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to explain this:

If you have a look at the following image, it shows the android lifecycle. As you see, the activity runs after the onCreate and the onPause, this means that even if you put some breakpoints in those methods, you won't see anything on the screen because the layout has not been updated yet.

In the debugger you can see the variables's values but not the values on the screen.

[image]

There is no utility on *debugging screen texts* because the utility of the debugger is debugging code, not layouts.

If you still want to debug the layout, your only way is to create a method on an action (for example a button click) and debugging this method.

Since the UI will be already drawn, you will see the texts updating but as I said before, there is no utility at seeing the layout updating, the point is seeing which values are for the variables at the line you are stopping at.

Hope that helped

Answer (score 1):

You've stopped the device during `onResume`. At this point nothing has actually been drawn, instead you've set the text values. After this function completes, the UI will get to be redrawn, and you'll see the changes. This is an optimisation that most UI development code makes.

Answer (score 0):

All the views will be visible on the screene when the activity lifecycle methods have completed i.e onCreate, onStart then onResume. Your device is stopped as you are debugging inside onResume. After onResume completes the views will be redrawn if already drawn and you will be able to see the result.

Comment: You should put a break point where you want the debugger to stop executing and wait for you to process your code step by step, or directly jump to the next break point. Break point will not end the execution of your code . You will be able to see your results once the lifecycle method has completed.